# Cannot index into a null array with two PSCustomObjects

Tags: powershell

My code builds two PSCustomObjects. Both objects can be `$null`, either Object can be `$null`. I test for that like this

```
$ADResult = @()
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($ADGroups)) {
    Write-Warning "No AD Groups"
    $ADResult = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        ADGroups                  = ""
        ADGroupsdistinguishedName = ""
    }
}
Else {
    foreach ($group in $ADGroups) { do stuff }
```

The problem is when both objects are `$null`.  When I put the objects together for a report. I get the error "Cannot index into a null array."

```
[int]$max = $ADResult.count
if ([int]$GResult.count -gt $max) { [int]$max = $GResult.count }

$Result = @()
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++) {
    $Result += [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        PrimaryEmail                 = $email
        Title                        = $UserInfo.title
        Department                   = $UserInfo.Department
        Manager                      = $Manager
        EmailBackup                  = $ENV:Backup
        AccountDisabled              = $ENV:ADDisabled
        GoogleRemoved                = $ENV:RemoveGoogle
        ADGroupName                  = $ADResult.ADGroups[$i]
        ADGroupNameDistinguishedName = $ADResult.ADGroupsdistinguishedName[$i]
        GoogleGroup                  = $GResult.GoogleGroups[$i]
        Role                         = $GResult.role[$i]
        DateOfSeparation             = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")
        UnixID                       = $unix
        UserDistinguishedName        = $UserInfo.distinguishedName
        UserOU                       = $UserInfo.Ou
        PrimaryGroup                 = $UserInfo.primaryGroup.Split('=').Split(',')[1]
    }
}
```

How can I overcome this better?
I want the other information like ou and related if both objects are `$null`

Comment: The first snippet only creates 1 object, with 2 _properties_. It looks like you're trying to align `$ADResult` and `$GResult` - what is `$GResult`?

Comment: You start with `$ADResult` and then you call it `$GPResult`. Anyways, try to [avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026)

Comment: The 2nd object is pretty much the same as the first @IRon. I use GAM to get a persons google groups

Comment: @dcaz And you're absolutely sure that the number of AD groups and the number of Google Groups is exactly the same? Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to loop over them together like this

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen they are not. That is why I do the `[int]$max = $ADResult.count
if ([int]$GResult.count -gt $max) { [int]$max = $GResult.count }`

Comment: I want to combine the results from both commands and then report. The issue I have is when both command results that build the objects are `$null`

Comment: In that case, change `""` to `@()` when you create the "empty" object properties

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen change that to the answer and I can accept it because that works.

Comment: If `$Max` represents the maximum number of `$ADResult` objects, it should be `$ADResult[$i].ADGroups` (not `$ADResult.ADGroups[$i]`) as it might be that `$ADResult` exists but has simply  no `ADGroups`. Anyways, it would help if you copy the exact error message (which the line that fails) ***into the question***.

Comment: @iRon can you come chat about += ?
[+=chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236856/building-an-object-with-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of the properties in your "empty" placeholder object from an empty string to a empty *array*:

```
$ADResult = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
    ADGroups                  = @()
    ADGroupsdistinguishedName = @()
}
```